# R sf - How to translate polygons?

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I have a dataset that looks like below which I can turn into an `sf` object:

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), geometry=c("POLYGON ((529411.4 178358.9, 529409.9 178358.4, 529408.5 178362.9, 529409.9 178363.3, 529411.4 178358.9))",
                                         "POLYGON ((529409.9 178363.5, 529408.4 178363.1, 529407 178367.5, 529408.4 178368, 529409.9 178363.5))",
                                         "POLYGON ((529408.4 178368.2, 529406.9 178367.7, 529405.5 178372.2, 529407 178372.7, 529408.4 178368.2))",
                                         "POLYGON ((529406.9 178372.9, 529405.4 178372.4, 529404 178376.9, 529405.5 178377.4, 529406.9 178372.9))",
                                         "POLYGON ((529405.4 178377.5, 529403.9 178377.1, 529402.5 178381.6, 529404 178382, 529405.4 178377.5))",
                                         "POLYGON ((529403.9 178382.2, 529402.4 178381.7, 529401 178386.2, 529402.5 178386.7, 529403.9 178382.2))"))

data <- data %>% st_as_sf(wkt="geometry", crs=27700)
```

The problem is there is an error in the original data whereby the polygons have been translated from their original position by X amount in the east direction and Y amount in north direction.

How can I translate this polygon by say 100 units up and 100 units right?

I'd expect there to by a function like `st_translate(100,100)`, although there doesn't seem to be.

How else can I translate the polygons using the `sf` or other package?

Comment: Have you seen the `sf` [affine transformations vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf3.html#affine-transformations)?

Comment: No I haven't, but it looks exactly like what I've been searching for, thank you!

Comment: No problem - If I hadn't come across it before then it's not the phrase I would have searched for either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to comment left by SamR, it looks like you can just overwrite the geometry of the sf object with a translation by simply adding a vector to the geometry:

```
st_geometry(data) <- st_geometry(data) + c(100, -100)
```

I couldn't find a way to do this as part of a pipe in a dplyr kind of way but this should be good enough.